# (Java) User selection of JTable row

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a JTable that lists customer information returned from an SQL query. How do I set up the table so the user can select one row, by perhaps double clicking or ticking a check box, and then JTextField is filled in with the chosen customer name?

Answer (score 3):

Here a sample code to go fwd

```
public class PersonTable {

    JTable table;

    public PersonTable() {
        final MyTableModel myTableModel = new MyTableModel();
        myTableModel.fill();

        table = new JTable(myTableModel);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Persons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        final JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);

        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                Object valueAt = myTableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
                t1.setText((String) valueAt);
            }
        });

        panel1.add(new JLabel("Name"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel1.add(t1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        String[] columnName = new String[]{"Customer Name", "Phone Number", "Area"};
        String[][] valueA = null;

        public void fill() {

            valueA = new String[3][columnName.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                valueA[i][0] = "Name" + i;
                valueA[i][1] = "989481125" + i;
                valueA[i][2] = "Area No" + i;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return valueA.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columnName[column];
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnName.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return valueA[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PersonTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the Java Swing Tutorial on how to use JTables. Basically, you write an Listener for row selection:

[How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

Comment: Err, sorry, my mistake. I wanted to say he will write a Listener.